# Правильно ли оформлена авторская речь в диалоге?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

У меня автор делает сложные диалоговые конструкции. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Правильно ли оформлена прямая речь?

> – Волшебники? Портал? – недоумевала девочка вслух. – Но зачем же вы…
> Ой! То есть ты. – Она каждый раз делала невероятное усилие, чтобы
> обращаться к малознакомому человеку, годившемуся ей в отцы, в такой
> простой и доверительной форме, но Фред, кажется, не обращал на это ни
> малейшего внимания. – оставил мне конверт? Я же совершенно
> обыкновенный человек.

или правильно будет так?

> – Волшебники? Портал? – недоумевала девочка вслух. – Но зачем же вы…
> Ой! То есть ты. – Она каждый раз делала невероятное усилие, чтобы
> обращаться к малознакомому человеку, годившемуся ей в отцы, в такой
> простой и доверительной форме, но Фред, кажется, не обращал на это ни
> малейшего внимания: – оставил мне конверт? Я же совершенно
> обыкновенный человек.

Двоеточие или точку в конце авторской речи лучше поставить?

Answer (score 2):

Может, так (два многоточия):

*– Волшебники? Портал? – недоумевала девочка вслух. – **Но зачем же вы… Ой! То есть ты...** — Она каждый раз делала невероятное усилие, чтобы обращаться к малознакомому человеку, годившемуся ей в отцы, в такой простой и доверительной форме, но Фред, кажется, не обращал на это ни малейшего внимания. —  **...оставил мне конверт? Я же совершенно обыкновенный человек**.*

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написала так (с разделением на абзацы):

> — Волшебники? Портал? — недоумевала девочка вслух. — Но зачем же вы... Ой! То есть ты.
> Она каждый раз делала невероятное усилие, чтобы обращаться к малознакомому человеку, годившемуся ей в отцы, в такой простой и доверительной форме, но Фред, кажется, не обращал на это ни малейшего внимания.
> — Оставил мне конверт? Я же совершенно обыкновенный человек.

[§ 53. Абзацы при прямой речи](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154#pp154) (Д. Э. Розенталь):

> Но если в тексте от автора описывается действие говорящего лица, то и авторский текст, и последующая прямая речь выделяются в абзацы:
> *— Формула эта может иметь и другой вид, — пояснил профессор.
>
> Он неторопливо подошёл к доске, взял мел и написал что-то новое для нас.
>
> — Вот это и есть другой вариант, — сказал он.*

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не разделял цельную фразу на абзацы. Фраза персонажа обрывается на середине и включает авторскую ремарку, которая не связана прямо с речью персонажа, а потому её следует писать с прописной буквы.
Я бы предложил многоточие:

> – Волшебники? Портал? – недоумевала девочка вслух. – Но зачем же вы…
> Ой! То есть ты... – Она каждый раз делала невероятное усилие, чтобы
> обращаться к малознакомому человеку, годившемуся ей в отцы, в такой
> простой и доверительной форме, но Фред, кажется, не обращал на это ни
> малейшего внимания. – Оставил мне конверт? Я же совершенно
> обыкновенный человек.